# Why does this c# code has two angular bracket '>>' after IHeapifyable in this line

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio, data-structures, delegates

The method is in a class Heap which creates a Heap data structure in C#
This method finds the Kth minimum value in O(K log n) time
What does this line exactly do

```
List<IHeapifyable<K, D>> temp = new List<IHeapifyable<K, D>>();
```

Can someone explain this specific line in a C# code
The whole code is over here

```
public IHeapifyable<K, D> KthMinElement(int k)
    {
        if (Count is 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        if (k <= 0 || k > Count) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        IHeapifyable<K, D> kthMin = null;
        List<IHeapifyable<K, D>> temp = new List<IHeapifyable<K, D>>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            if (i == k) kthMin = data[1];
            temp.Add(this.Delete());
        }
        foreach (var node in temp) this.Insert(node.Key, node.Data);

        return kthMin;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle brackets are the opening and closing of what is contained in the data type they are describing.

```
List<IHeapifyable<K, D>> temp = new List<IHeapifyable<K, D>>();
```

So what this line says is:  Create a `List` data type containing one or more `IHeapifyable<K,D>` data types and assign it to the variable `temp`

A List of integers is initialized with this

```
List<int>
```

Your example is the same except instead of `int` it's

```
IHeaplifyable<K,D>
```

so if you replace the `int` with `IHeaplifyable` you get.

```
List<IHeaplifyable<K,D>>
```

Comment: But why does it have >> at the ending,  <K, D>>
Generally we have only <K, D>

Comment: @somil the second `>` is the closing for the `List<`

Comment: @Somil  I edited my answer to break it down further.

Answer (score 3):

The angle brackets are enclosing the generic type parameters. It's using a `List<T>` where `T` is `IHeapifyable<K, D>`, so it's a `List<IHeapifyable<K, D>>`. It's just like if you were to nest method calls like this:

```cs
Method1(Method2(arg));
```

so you end up with two closing parentheses at the end.